# How to call a default constructor defined in another cpp file

Tags: c++

I am trying to call a default constructor Process() from another(main.cpp) file.

process.h:

```cpp
#ifndef PROCESS_H
#define PROCESS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

// Car class with its attributes
class Process {
  public:
    std::string mbox;   
    std::string msg;
    // Car(int year, std::string model, std::string brand);

    Process(); /* Sending the default message */
    Process(const std::string& arg);
    Process(std::vector<std::string> args);

  void operator()();
};

#endif
```

process.cpp:

```cpp
#include <simgrid/s4u.hpp>
#include <string>
#include "process.h"

std::string mbox  = "mb42";
std::string msg = "GaBuZoMeu";


explicit Process() = default;

Process::Process(const std::string& arg) : msg(arg) { /* Sending the specified message */}

Process::Process(std::vector<std::string> args) { 
     xbt_assert(args.size() >= 3, "The sender is expecting 2 parameters from the deployment file but got %zu",
               args.size() - 1);
    msg  = args[1];
    mbox = args[2];

void operator()() /* This is the main code of the actor */
  {
    XBT_INFO("Hello s4u, I have something to send");
    simgrid::s4u::Mailbox* mailbox = simgrid::s4u::Mailbox::by_name(mbox);

    mailbox->put(new std::string(msg), msg.size());
    XBT_INFO("I'm done. See you.");
  }
}
```

main.cpp:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    simgrid::s4u::Engine e(&argc, argv);
    /* Load the platform description and then deploy the application */
    xbt_assert(argc==2, "Usage: %s resources/datazero_platform.xml", argv[0]);
    e.load_platform(argv[1]);

    std::vector<simgrid::s4u::Host *> hosts = e.get_all_hosts();
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < e.get_host_count(); i++)
    {
        XBT_INFO("Host name: %s", hosts[i] -> get_name().c_str());
        XBT_INFO("Turning on the host...");
        
        hosts[i] -> turn_on();
        if (hosts[i] -> is_on())
        {
            XBT_INFO("Host is on.");
            simgrid::s4u::Actor::create("sample", simgrid::s4u::Host::by_name(hosts[i] -> get_name().c_str()) ,Process());
        } else {
            XBT_INFO("Host is off.");
        }
        
        XBT_INFO("Host core count: %i", hosts[i] -> get_core_count());
        XBT_INFO("Host speed: %f", hosts[i] -> get_speed());
    }

    /* Run the simulation */
    e.run();
    XBT_INFO("Total simulation time: %.3f", e.get_clock());
    return 0;
}
```

While building the project, I get the below error:

```
/home/shreya/Documents/CSA/Project Materials/datazero_s4u/src/process.cpp:9:18: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
 explicit Process() = default;
```

Comment: It should be `Process::Process()`.  Also IIRC, `explicit` should go on the declaration, not the definition.

Comment: @0x5453 on top of that it does not make sense to declare default ctor explicit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TL;DR

Remove `explicit Process() = default;` from the cpp file. In the class definition change `Process();` to `Process() = default;`

## Explanation

Defaulting a constructor, destructor, or special member function is done in the class definition. Once defaulted, nothing else need be done.

In addition, `explicit` is used to prevent unintended conversion. You can't convert with a default constructor, so it can be removed. If you want to make use of `explicit`, apply it to the other two constructors that can be used to accidentally convert a `std::string` or a `std::vector` to a `Process`.

## Side notes

The includes in process.h are a bit off. `<iostream>` and `<string.h>` are not used by the header, but `<string>` and `<vector>` are.

`void operator()()` in process.cpp needs to know its class and should be
`void Process::operator()()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

You are missing qualifications:

```
Process::Process() = default;
void Process::operator()() /* This is the main code of the actor */
{/*blah blah blah*/};
```

and the `explicit` keyword must be place inside the class declaration:

```
class Process {
    //...
    explicit Process();
    //...
};
```

cheers,
FM.

Comment: `explicit` can be just removed here, it does not do anything

Comment: I see. But if the OP wants it...